# bind button onClick method to keypress action

Tags: button, onclick, bind, keypress

I have a button b, I want the document to understand a key press action has been triggered whenever I click on that button.

For example, when i click on that button, i want the document to recognize that the left key has been pressed and whatever the java script has been written for it should work.

I am unable to figure out how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to look for a click action. You can do this for a specific button, the first button that your code finds, or all buttons on the page if they all perform the same action. Actually, you can add this listener to just about any html object. Here's a simple snippet I got from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/element.addEventListener.

```js
<div id="ear">Click me</div>
<div id="display"></div>

<script>

  var ear = document.getElementById('ear');
  ear.addEventListener("click", listener, false);

  function listener() {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "blah blah";
  }

</script>
```

What this is doing is creating a variable called ear, and assigning the div with id='ear' to it. Again, you can just as easily do this with a button, or any other tag. Then `ear.addEventListener` adds a `click` event, tells it to run the `listener` function, and the boolean at the end says if the parent's handlers should be run, as well all ancestors going up. Setting this to `true` will cause only the tag that was clicked to run.